# How does one end processing and return a response message using MessageProcessingHandler?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I stumbled across the `MessageProcessingHandler` class in WebAPI.   It's a child of `DelegatingHandler`.   There's almost no information out there on the class and MS documentation is particularly thin, simply saying:

> The `MessageProcessingHandler` is useful if the handler doesn't require
>   asynchronous operations, because operations on request and response
>   messages are fast. The most common usage is to derive from this class
>   and override the `ProcessRequest` and `ProcessResponse` methods.

So I thought I'd take the class out for a spin, see how it feels.  I'm stumped on one thing... **how can I end the processing pipeline and send a `ResponseMessage` back?**

For example: say I have a handler that checks for authentication, the check fails, and I want to return an HTTP 401/403 (I'm not saying which so  I can avoid a [holy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220432/http-401-unauthorized-or-403-forbidden-for-a-disabled-user) [war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/) :-).   It doesn't seem possible with `MessageProcessingHandler`. Right?

Comment: `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new YourMessageHandler());` in `global.asax` worked for me

Comment: Did the comment-answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

As we can see the `MessageProcessingHandler` inherit from `DelegatingHandler`, and i found:

Firstly, we can't implement `SendAsync` method in implementation class of `HttpMessageHandler`, because it's sealed. But as we can see from MS docs, If we implement a `DelegatingHandler`, we can skip the inner handler and directly create the response in `SendAsync` override method.

Secondly, `ProcessRequest` method takes an `HttpRequestMessage` as input and returns an `HttpRequestMessage`, it won't return `HttpResponseMessage`. `ProcessResponse` do return reponse, but it will be excute after action finish executing.

Finally, `MessageProcessingHandler` class comments say:

> A base type for handlers which only do some small processing of
>   request and/or response messages.

So the answer is obvious, `ProcessRequest` don't send a `ResponseMessage` back, but only do **some small processing**. btw, some people also log here and return original request.