# HTTP Status Code for Authenticated but Unauthorized?

Tags: rest, api, http, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-401

With which HTTP status code should a REST API respond if the request is authenticated (according to [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage: Authorization Request Header Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1)) but the authenticated user is unauthorized to view the resource being requested?

For example, imagine I make a request to see a certain user's profile: `GET /users/123`. I authenticate successfully, but that user has blocked me. With which HTTP status code should the server respond?

Related:

- [Authentication versus Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556522/authentication-versus-authorization)
- [HTTP status code for missing authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301877/http-status-code-for-missing-authentication)

Comment: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#status.403

Comment: Here's a useful [guide](http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/) for choosing an appropriate HTTP Status Code

Comment: Does my answer resolve your doubts?

Comment: Yes, thank you @Opal. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you need is `403 Forbidden`:

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403):

> A 403 response generally indicates one of two conditions:
>
> - Authentication was provided, but the authenticated user is not permitted to perform the requested operation.
> - The operation is forbidden to all users. For example, requests for a directory listing return code 403 when directory listing has been
>     disabled.