# How do I raise a Response Forbidden in django

Tags: django

I'd like to do the following:

```
raise HttpResponseForbidden()
```

But I get the error:

```
exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not HttpResponseForbidden
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

Return it from the view as you would any other response.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: Why does there exists an exception class `Http404` but not `Http403`? Why the inconsistency?

Comment: @Flimm http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses I'm not sure about Django, but Django REST Framework has:  from rest_framework import status
status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
403

Comment: Actually using `raise PermissionDenied` has the advantage of letting you show your custom 403 view

Comment: I think that the question asks for a very specific thing and this answer does not answer that specific thing, but show another approach. See the answer below, which answers the very specific question - and IMO it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Flimm indeed...

Answer (score 468):

if you want to raise an exception you can use:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def your_view(...):
    raise PermissionDenied()
```

It is documented here :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view

As opposed to returing `HttpResponseForbidden`, raising `PermissionDenied` causes the error to be rendered using the `403.html` template, or you can use middleware to show a custom "Forbidden" view.

Comment: You can still provide middleware with a process_exception method and render your view from there.

Comment: Can we add a custom message in PermissionDenied?

Comment: Jack, yes you can -- do something like: raise PermissionDenied("No logged in user")

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but the docs say `throw PermissionDenied` not as a function call, without the `()` at the end.

Comment: What's the advantage of using this over HttpResponseForbidden?

Comment: @Flimm: This automatically triggers 403 at middleware level, allowing you to show your custom "Forbidden" view.

Comment: @MarkChackerian any idea of `PermissionDenied` in Django 1.6. I created a custom 403.html . How to retrieve the custom message in html ? . `raise PermissionDenied("custom message")` dont show my custom message

Comment: Using this in an admin view and still getting 500 instead of 403. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 14):

You can optionally supply a custom template named **"403.html"** to control the rendering of 403 HTTP errors.

As correctly pointed out by @dave-halter, *The 403 template can only be used if you raise PermissionDenied*

Below is a sample view used to test custom templates "403.html", "404.html" and "500.html"; **please make sure to set DEBUG=False in project's settings** or the framework will show a traceback instead for 404 and 500.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied


def index(request):

    html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="?action=raise403">Raise Error 403</a></li>
        <li><a href="?action=raise404">Raise Error 404</a></li>
        <li><a href="?action=raise500">Raise Error 500</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
"""

    action = request.GET.get('action', '')
    if action == 'raise403':
        raise PermissionDenied
    elif action == 'raise404':
        raise Http404
    elif action == 'raise500':
        raise Exception('Server error')

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Comment: This does not work. The 403 template can only be used if you raise PermissionDenied.

Comment: Thank you @dave-halter, you'r right. I updated my comment to correct it.

Answer (score 5):

Try this Way , sending message with Error

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
raise PermissionDenied("You do not have permission to Enter Clients in Other Company, Be Careful")
```