# django response issue 403 for unauthorized

Tags: django

In the following code how to issue 403 for unauthorized?

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
  if user is not None:
     # the password verified for the user
     if user.is_active:
       print("User is valid, active and authenticated")
       return HttpResponse("Authorized")
     else:
       print("The password is valid, but the account has been disabled!")
       return HttpResponse("Unauthorized")
  else:
      # the authentication system was unable to verify the username and password
      print("The username and password were incorrect.")
      return HttpResponse("Unauthorized")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I raise a Response Forbidden in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618939/how-do-i-raise-a-response-forbidden-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [`HttpResponseForbidden`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden).

> Acts just like [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) but uses a 403 status code.