# How to create a page to show that user had reach the call API limit with django python

Tags: python, django

So I am making an project that call user API from github and after 60 times I will get this error:

[image]

And I want if user got that error I want it return a page like this:
[image]

How can I do that ?

Comment: HTTP rate limits are there to stop users from abusing a service. You will have to throttle your requests, so that you don't hit this limit

Comment: Another possibility would be to use proxies to call this API. This way the limit will be multiplied by the number of IPs that you have

Comment: but if I hit the limit can i return render a page like for this error ?

Comment: all you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618939/how-do-i-raise-a-response-forbidden-in-django

Comment: These two is what you need https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/views/ https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views