# django shows 500 error instead of 403 error

Tags: python, django, django-errors

I was trying to write custom error pages and got this issue, when a user is not authenticated and tries to visit a specific webpage I returned PermissionDenied() handler to show a 403(expected by me) but, django shows a 500 error instead. How do I show a 403 error in this case?

My urls.py:

```py
handler404 = 'error.views.error_404'
handler403 = 'error.views.error_403'
handler500 = 'error.views.error_500'
handler400 = 'error.views.error_400'
```

My views.py to authenticate the user:

```py
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request,"app/index.html")
else:
    return PermissionDenied()
```

My views.py used to handle exceptions:

```py
def error_404(request, exception):
    data = {}
    return render(request,'error/404.html', data)

def error_403(request, exception):
    data = {}
    return render(request,'error/403.html', data)

def error_500(request):
    data = {}
    return render(request,'error/500.html', data)

def error_400(request, exception):
    data = {}
    return render(request,'error/400.html', data)
```

Reference Used: [How do I raise a Response Forbidden in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618939/how-do-i-raise-a-response-forbidden-in-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *raise* [**`PermissionDenied`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/exceptions/#permissiondenied) as an exception, so:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request,"app/index.html")
else:
    raise PermissionDenied()
```

or you can return a [**`HttpResponseForbidden`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseForbidden):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return render(request,"app/index.html")
else:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

but you can not merge the two and return a `PermissionDenied`, or `raise` a `HttpResponseForbidden`: `PermissionDenied` is an exception whereas `HttpResponseForbidden` is a HTTP response.