# What does a HTTP 403 error mean?

Tags: jsf, http-status-code-403

I am using JSF 2.0, Eclipse indigo, Tomcat 7.
I am getting this error but can see nothing on console.
I am working on a project that is built some one else, and there are lines in `web.xml`.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/error/error403.jsf</location>
</error-page>
```

What might the problem be?

Comment: I'm not sure what your concrete problem/question is. Are you getting 403 errors and wondering why you're getting this error? In other words, you do not understand what a HTTP 403 Forbidden error means?

Comment: yes, i can say yes. some time ago, i used to get this error but that time there were server was starting with lots of errors. but now there is no exception in server starting console. thanks for response

Comment: In the future try to state the concrete question clearly in the question title. I've edited it for you.

Comment: Similar: [403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3297048/55075)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [HTTP 403 Forbidden](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4) error means that *nobody* is authorized to request the given URL. Different credentials also won't help (that's the difference with [HTTP 401 Unauthorized](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) error). You see this error often when you attempt to open a folder on the webserver with the intention to get a directory index with a list of files, but the server has it disabled and there is no index (welcome) file.

Note that this is **unrelated** to JSF.

Comment: It's related to JSF because it occurs for almost every user attempting to import a project in Eclipse through a ZIP file.

Comment: @Mathias: nope, it can also happen on non-JSF projects using Java EE container managed authentication.