# Should I return a 401 or a 405 response code to a REST API user without sufficient access?

Tags: api, http, rest, httpresponse, http-status-codes

I'm developing an API which will also have an authentication/authorization component.

Anybody, regardless of authentication status, will be able to write (POST), but depending on if you are unauthenticated, authenticated as a normal user or authenticated as an admin and what resource you are trying to access I'm going to return different responses for GET, DELETE and PUT.

I'm trying to figure out the most appropriate response code for a user who isn't authenticated and/or authorized.

Keep in mind http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html:

> Unauthorized -> 401
>
> Forbidden -> 403
>
> Method Not Allowed -> 405

Let's use a specific examples:

- John Doe is unauthenticated, on DELETE should he receive a 401 or a 405?
- Amy is authenticated but not authorized, on DELETE should she receive a 403 or a 405?

(Keep in mind that even though John and Amy are forbidden or unauthorized that doesn't mean they arent able to access the same resource with a different HTTP VERB.)

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses

Comment: So John should get a 401, Amy should get a 403.

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed seems [totally unrelated](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Comment: @minitech well the thing is *other* methods are still allowed, e.g., GET might be allowed even where DELETE is disallowed. So it seems that one might want to do a 405 to make it clear that the *entire resource* isnt disallowed only this particular VERB associated with it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`405 Method Not Allowed` should only be used if *you* don't support the method. It shouldn't be used to tell *the client* that they cannot use this method.

So the only good HTTP code in your case would be `401 Unauthorized`. It indicates the client that the method exists and that they need to login to access it.

Comment: Almost.  Once you have been authenticated, but are not allowed to do the operation, it'll be 403.

Comment: @JulianReschke, hmmm not sure. For 403, the standard states that "Unlike a 401 Unauthorized response, authenticating will make no difference". But in this case, authenticating *would* make a difference since it would allow accessing the resource.

Comment: Laurent: "The server understood the request, but refuses to authorize it. Providing different user authentication credentials might be successful, but any credentials that were provided in the request are insufficient. The request SHOULD NOT be repeated with the same credentials." -- http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-latest.html#status.403

Answer (score 45):

In this case, I think providing some examples for clarification are useful:

- Unauthenticated + Supported method = `401`
- Unauthenticated + Unsupported method = `405`
- Authenticated + Authorized + Supported method = `2xx`
- Authenticated + Authorized + Unsupported method = `405`
- Authenticated + Unauthorized + Supported method = `403`
- Authenticated + Unauthorized + Unsupported method = `405`

In other words, from a procedural standpoint:

1. Check whether methods are supported. If not: `405`
2. If supported, check if the user is authenticated. If not: `401`
3. If authenticated, check if the user is authorized. If not: `403`
4. If authorized: `2xx`

**EDIT:** I stumbled upon this diagram and thought it might be useful to anyone else who might stumble across this post. Click to enlarge.

[image]

Original [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/for-GET/http-decision-diagram/master/httpdd.png).

Comment: Wow, that is incredibly detailed. I pray to the developer gods I will never need to use more than 5% of this flow chart.

Comment: It should be noted that although `401` is actually `401 Unauthorized`, and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses) has some lengthy, undecisive discussions on when should `401` or `403` be used.