# Return HTTP 401 and say client DO NOT repeat request

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-mvc-3, http-status-codes, http-status-code-401

We implemented custom authentication. User name and password are send in request body. If user or password is invalid then Server returns HTTP 401. Server is implemented with C#, MVC3 and .NET 4.0.

We faced the problem that if client received 401 then it automatically resends the same request 2 times. Actually this is issue for iOS only. iOS guys said that it happens on low level and it is out of control in application. So probably server should be able to say client do not send request again.

This is problem for us because we use Active Directory and in case of invalid password we spend 3 attempts instead of just one. So account becomes locked very soon and unexpectedly.

I found this [document](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2) that says

> **401 Unauthorized**
>
> ... The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field.

How to return HTTP 401 and say to client DO NOT repeat request anymore?

Answer (score 1):

You may use 403 instead:

From [W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) site:

> **10.4.4 403 Forbidden**
>
> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
>   Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.

Indeed, this is a little tricky: 403 seems more appropriate when authentication was successful, but the resource requested is not allowed for the specific user, which is not your case. However, 403 means client should not repeat authentication, and this is what you want.

If the login page is to be interpreted only by humans, then you may consider returning "200 OK" and simply display the login page again (perhaps with a visible indication to the user that the login has failed).

Comment: Yes, I think about this option... But we already have some versions of client which work with 401. It should work for them as well without changing HTTP code. On other hand 401 is more proper for not authenticated (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses).