# Why does SessionAuthentication in Django REST Framework Never Return HTTP401

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Looking at [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#sessionauthentication) and [the source](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/29bcce70135d9fccd8d27a5e425f756363e28700/rest_framework/authentication.py#L101) of the Django REST Framework, I see that `SessionAuthentication` only ever returns an HTTP 403 code whereas other `Authentication` classes will return 401. What is the reason for this?

There are certainly plenty of cases where [401 makes sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses).

The issue is especially problematic since " The first authentication class set on the view is used when determining the type of response." and `SessionAuthentication` is by default the first `Authentication` class.

Answer (score 11):

Django REST Framework adheres to the [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2), and does not return a 401 response when the `Authentication` class does not return a `WWW-Authenticate` header that can be used.

> HTTP 401 responses must always include a `WWW-Authenticate` header, that instructs the client how to authenticate. HTTP 403 responses do not include the `WWW-Authenticate` header.
>
> -- [Django REST Framework documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#unauthorized-and-forbidden-responses)

Because the `SessionAuthentication` class does not define a `WWW-Authenticate` header that can  be used, Django REST Framework cannot return 401 responses and still follow the specification. You can get around this by setting another `Authentication` class that supports the header to the top of your list, such as [`BasicAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#basicauthentication).