# Authentication of RESTful Endpoints - Basic Authentication and XHR

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

What is the right way to have a REST endpoint support [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and work with XHR?

I am using the Django REST Framework (DRF) to create a set of REST endpoints. These endpoints will be used by an single-page application (SPA) through a set of XHR (AJAX) calls as well from a C++ application. The C++ application is currently using the Qt framework. Within the Qt framework, I am using [QNetworkAccessManager](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#authenticationRequired) along with [QAuthenticator](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qauthenticator.html). The `authenticationRequired` signal is emitted "whenever a final server requests authentication" which I believe is driven by the `WWW-Authenticate` header in a 401 response (I am currently using [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)).

I am trying to figure out how to set up Authentication in Django REST to make both my SPA and the C++ application happy. I posted this question: [Why does SessionAuthentication in Django REST Framework Never Return HTTP401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600969/why-does-sessionauthentication-in-django-rest-framework-never-return-http401) and what I learned is that I can get 401s (with the `WWW-Authenticate`  header) from DRF if I set the first Authentication class to `BasicAuthentication`. This however causes the browser to popup a modal login dialog when it receives the 401.

What is the best way to make the browser happy and provide the 401s with `WWW-Authenticate` header? One idea would be to use one Authentication class for requests from the C++ app and a different Authentication class for requests from a browser.

Login box on Chrome:
[image: login_box]

Answer (score 1):

The way I ended up solving this was to subclass `BasicAuthentication` and override `authenticate_header` to return the `401` code with the `WWW-Authenticate` header only if a certain header is set in the request. Any client needing the 401 code (e.g. the C++ Application) make sure to set this header value in all of the requests that it makes. In DRF settings, I then set this authentication class as the first class and then put `SessionAuthentication` second.

Answer (score 0):

If the client knows a priori that the server requires basic authentication for a resource, it can include the Authorization header with each request and avoid receiving the 401 (Unauthorized) response with the WWW-Authorization header.

On the client (both javascript and c++), concatenate the client identifier (e.g., the username if the client is making a request on behalf of a user) and the shared secret (such as a password) as `<identifier>:<secret>`, and then compute a Base64 encoding of this text. Include the value of the resulting text in an Authorization header in client requests:

```
Authorization: Basic <Base64 encoded value>
```