# What HTTP error code for POST'ing resource with wrong relations ownership?

Tags: api, rest

Given I want to create a resource which has many `subresources`.
The given parameters look like this:

```
{  
    "data":{  
        "name":"foo",
        "subresources":[  
            {  
                "id":1
            },
            {  
                "id":2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What HTTP error should I return if the current user is not allowed to see the subresource with id = 2?

I considered those:

- 400: invalid_parameter - validation at the api entry point level
- 422: invalid_record - validation at the model level
- 404: not_found - because this is what the user gets if he is not authorized to `GET /subresources/2`
- 403: forbidden - because you're not allowed to see this resource

Thank you for your help.

**Update: I'm also considering 403.**

Answer (score 2):

If a user with the correct credentials *could* make this request to the server successfully, then the appropriate response would be [401 - Unauthorized](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E401.html).

In your error message, it would be prudent to indicate that you want to reject the request because a specific value is not available to that user; this way, the request can be retried by the client sans anything they aren't able to access.

Comment: 401 Not authorized is about authentication, not authorization.
The user is logged here, so I don't think 401 would fit here.

Comment: @Erem:  Could you say that again?  Are you saying that "Not Authorized" is about **authentication**? Are you *sure* that's correct?

Comment: I'm saying 401 'not-authorized-authenticated-or-whatever-you-want-to-call-it' means the credentials you provided are not enough to identify an account. So yeah, I'm talking about authentication here.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/692751

Authorization means: "Okay you're logged but you don't have sufficient privileges to perform this action."

Is there something wrong with my statements?

Answer (score 1):

See the [list of HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html); you're probably looking for the "401 - Not Authorized" code.

Comment: 401 Not authorized is about authentication, not authorization.
The user is logged here, so I don't think 401 would fit here.