# WebSocket failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, websocket, wildfly

I'm working on wildfly 8.2. if I run a WebSocket connection to

```
var wsUrl = 'ws://' + window.location.host 

var ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl + '/testwebservlet')
```

On my server I have this msg in my console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8282/testwebservlet' failed:
    Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

My xhtml code is like below !!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>WebSocket Client</title>
<script type="text/javascript">      
 var wsUrl = 'ws://' + window.location.host 
 var ws = new WebSocket(wsUrl + '/testwebservlet')

     ws.onopen = function()
     {
        alert("Web Socket is connected!!");                 
     };
     ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
     {                  
        var msg = evt.data;
        alert("Message received:" +  msg);
     };
     ws.onclose = function()
     { 
        alert("Connection is closed..."); 
     };

  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

java code:

```
package testwebservlet;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

@ServerEndpoint("/testwebservlet")
public class WSEndpoint {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @OnMessage
    public void receiveMessage(String message, Session session) {
        log.info("Received : "+ message + ", session:" + session.getId());
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) {
        log.info("Open session:" + session.getId());         
    }

    @OnClose
    public void close(Session session, CloseReason c) {
        log.info("Closing:" + session.getId());
    }
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: so it works on wildfly 9?

Comment: So it is not a specific wildfly-8 problem like your tag suggests?

Comment: You **know** what an http 403 is, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses

Comment: @Kukeltje : WildFly is another headache lacking several rudimentary functionalities. 403 is constantly encountered on public WebSockets endpoints in WildFly 10.0.0 final.

Comment: @Tiny: I never have this 403 on wildfly 8.2. But what functionalities are missing in 10? Can't seem to find a link to/about this

Comment: steve, are you using any authentication framework? By the way, "webservlet" is an awkward name for an endpoint which would only confuse yourself and others. @Tiny: I never faced this kind of 403 problem during developing/testing <o:socket> on WF 8/9/10 (both Eclipse-managed and standalone, even in production).