# Return HTTP 403 using Authorize attribute in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When using ASP.Net WebAPI, I used to have a [custom `Authorize` attribute](https://github.com/civicsource/http/blob/3c057dd79d9ce31cb4016adf4b2867a86ca080aa/Core/AuthorizeCorrectlyAttribute.cs) I would use to return either an HTTP `403` or `401` depending on the situation. e.g. if the user is not authenticated, return a `401`; if the user is authenticated but doesn't have the appropriate permissions, return a `403`. [See here for more discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses) on that.

It seems now, in the new ASP.Net Core, they [don't want you overriding the `Authorize` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/316108) anymore instead favoring a policy-based approach. However, it seems Core MVC suffers from the same "just return `401` for all auth errors" approach its predecessors have.

How do I override the framework to get the behavior I want?

Comment: According to @blowdart, if the MVC6 Authorize attribute is still returning 401's instead of 403's when a user is authenticated but unauthorized, there is either a bug that should be filed or you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I just assumed it was by design that it was returning 401's no matter the scenario. If that behavior is not expected, I'll file a bug in aspnet/security.

Comment: See last comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/304832

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After opening an [issue here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/720), it appears this actually should work...sort of.

In your `Startup.Configure`, if you just call `app.UseMvc()` and don't register any other middleware, you will get `401` for any auth-related errors (not authenticated, authenticated but no permission).

If, however, you register one of the authentication middlewares that support it, you will correctly get `401` for unauthenticated and `403` for no permissions. For me, I used the `JwtBearerMiddleware` which allows authentication via a [JSON Web Token](https://jwt.io/). The key part is to set the `AutomaticChallenge` option when creating the middleware:

in `Startup.Configure`:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});
app.UseMvc();
```

`AutomaticAuthenticate` will set the `ClaimsPrincipal` automatically so you can access `User` in a controller. `AutomaticChallenge` allows the auth middleware to modify the response when auth errors happen (in this case setting `401` or `403` appropriately).

If you have your own authentication scheme to implement, you would inherit from `AuthenticationMiddleware` and `AuthenticationHandler` similar to how the [JWT implementation works](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/a5b288897d2981c241133b8d37aa22136b653e3a/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer).

Comment: I'm not using JwtBearerAuthentication, but, using cookie auth. Setting AutomaticChallenge = true results in automatic redirects when failing authorization.  I don't want redirects, but, 403's. From what I can see in the docs, this isn't possble.

Comment: Cookie auth was the default back with "FormsAuthentication" in the webforms days. I think the behavior is modeled off of that. e.g. if someone isn't authenticated, you want to redirect them to a login page after which a cookie will be set with their auth token. If you want cookie auth AND the behavior of JWT, you will probably need to implement a custom authentication scheme using `AuthenticationMiddleware` & `AuthenticationHandler`

Comment: Great answer.  Fixed a huge problem for me.  Thanks!

Comment: how can we use this in Identity Core 2? there's no such options avalable there

Comment: Looks like this works out of box for .net 6.

Answer (score 12):

I ended up doing it with middleware:

```
public class AuthorizeCorrectlyMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public AuthorizeCorrectlyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await next(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //the user is authenticated, yet we are returning a 401
                //let's return a 403 instead
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which should be registered in `Startup.Configure` before calling `app.UseMvc()`.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest, but not sure how you could apply it only to certain controllers / actions like you can with an attribute.

Comment: this is dangerous because writing to a HttpResponse (by setting statuscode in this case) after calling next middleware/delegate with next(context) will throw exception in case when some other middleware in the pipeline started writing response already.

Comment: forgot to mention....You should at least check context.Response.HasStarted == false before modifying the statuscode.

Answer (score 7):

I followed the guide for *Custom Authorization Policy Providers using IAuthorizationPolicyProvider in ASP.NET Core* and also wanted to create a custom response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-5.0

The guide I followed for that was *Customize the behavior of AuthorizationMiddleware*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-5.0

My code finally looked like this:

```
public class GuidKeyAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
         DefaultHandler = new AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler();

    public async Task HandleAsync(
        RequestDelegate requestDelegate,
        HttpContext httpContext,
        AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy,
        PolicyAuthorizationResult policyAuthorizationResult)
    {

        if (policyAuthorizationResult.Challenged && !policyAuthorizationResult.Succeeded && authorizationPolicy.Requirements.Any(requirement => requirement is GuidKeyRequirement))
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
            return;
        }

        // Fallback to the default implementation.
        await DefaultHandler.HandleAsync(requestDelegate, httpContext, authorizationPolicy,
                               policyAuthorizationResult);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler,
    GuidKeyAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler>();
```

You can also edit your `AuthorizationHandler` and access httpContext
via `IHttpContextAccessor`. However this feels more like a hack.

```
internal class GuidKeyAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<GuidKeyRequirement>
{
    private readonly ILogger<GuidKeyAuthorizationHandler> _logger;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public GuidKeyAuthorizationHandler(ILogger<GuidKeyAuthorizationHandler> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    // Check whether a given GuidKeyRequirement is satisfied or not for a particular context
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, GuidKeyRequirement requirement)
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext; // Access context here

        var key = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(httpContext.Request.QueryString.Value).Get("key");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
        {
            // If the user guid key matches mark the authorization requirement succeeded
            if (Guid.TryParse(key, out var guidKey) && guidKey == requirement.Key)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Guid key is correct");

                if (requirement.RequireRefererHeader)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Require correct referer header");
                    httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Referer", out var refererHeader);
                    if (requirement.RefererHeader == refererHeader)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("Referer header is correct");
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation($"Referer header {refererHeader} is not correct");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("Correct referer header is not needed");
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"Guid key {guidKey} is not correct");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("No guid key present");
        }
        var msg = "Invalid Guid";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Found that solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861098/3850405

Comment: Thank you. I tried to follow [original](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-7.0) `SampleAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler` but `AuthorizationFailure` is always null. I didn't find a way how to fill it in my AuthorizationHandler. So, finally fallen back to your solution: `policy.Requirements.Any(requirement => requirement is MyRequirement)` instead.