# How to correctly return a 404 from an AuthorizationHandler to prevent information disclosure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am writing an Authorisation Handler to remove a lot of boilerplate code from being in controllers.

I want to make sure I am doing this correctly as it seems a little weird to be calling "Succeed" on a requirement when it's actually failing. Note the line in the code below `//-> see explanation above!`

It's important that we do not disclose the ABN's that are stored within our System if you do not have access to the ABN vs you cannot perform an operation on an ABN that you have access to but you don't have the required permission level.

All the examples that I've found for requirements seem to consider that you either can or cannot perform some action.

This question is talking about the statuscodes I want to use, but I'm just not sure how to implement correctly with AspnetCore 
[Prevent Information Disclosure Http Status Codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038981/is-it-ok-to-return-a-http-401-for-a-non-existent-resource-instead-of-404-to-prev)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApi.Common.Authorisation;

namespace WebApi.App.Requirements
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the authorisation of the Current user attempting to access an ABN.
    /// If the user has an assocation with an ABN, but they cant perform the operation on it, then return 403 no
    /// If the user has no association with the ABN, then we don't want to disclose that the other ABN exists within the system at all so 404, 
    /// </summary>
    public class TaxEntityHandler : AuthorizationHandler<TaxEntity>
    {
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, TaxEntity requirement)
        {
            var userIdentifier = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ApiClaims.ContactClaimType);
            if (userIdentifier == null)
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
            else
            {
                var authorizationFilterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;

                if (authorizationFilterContext.RouteData.Values.TryGetValue("abn", out var abnValue))
                {
                    var abn = (string)abnValue;

                    var accessLevel = AccessHelper.DetermineAccess(context.User, abn);
                    if (accessLevel == EntityAccessLevel.None)
                    {
//-> see explanation above!
                        authorizationFilterContext.Result = new NotFoundResult();
                        context.Succeed(requirement);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((accessLevel & requirement.Level) == accessLevel)
                        {
                            context.Succeed(requirement);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Fail();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

The full implementation above works but seems weird.

I also experimented with this block, but that resulted in exceptions being fired all through the stack because of IsStarted on the httpresponse object, but it also actually gave back a 404. If I wrote nothing to the response, a 403 still was delivered.

```
if (accessLevel == EntityAccessLevel.None)
{
    authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.Response.Body))
    {
        sw.Write(NoData);
    }
    context.Fail();
}
```

And finally if I just set the status code and failed the context, then a 403 was delivered.

```
if (accessLevel == EntityAccessLevel.None)
{
    authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
    context.Fail();
}
```

If there is a better example of doing this I would to know

Comment: IMO, I would prefer the final way  which will return 404 and from code, it is better to understand with `context.Fail();`.

Comment: I agree but the 403 is still delivered.

Comment: this post is usefull for this question please look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889688/how-to-change-status-code-add-message-from-failed-authorizationhandler-policy

Comment: Please note: If your own `HandleRequirementAsync` causes `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in Chrome then look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449533/asp-net-authorizationhandlers-response-upsets-chrome-causes-neterr-http2-pr