# Asp.Net AuthorizationHandler's response upsets Chrome, causes "net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Tags: asp.net-core, google-chrome-devtools, .net-6.0, asp.net-authorization

I've decided to write a custom AuthorizationHandler for a custom Policy I'm using :

```
// I pass this to AddPolicy in startup.cs
public class MyRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement {

    public MyRequirement () { ... }
}



public class MyAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement> {


    public MyAuthorizationHandler() { }


    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement) {

        if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext) {
            var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();

            if ( /* conditions for hard failure */ ) { context.Fail(); return; }
            
            if ( /* conditions for success */) { context.Succeed(requirement); return; }

            // Neither a success nor a failure, simply a different response.
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Blah blah NotFound").ConfigureAwait(false);
            return;
        }

        context.Fail();
    }
}
```

**I've seen similar code snippets in other StackOverlflow answers.** (e.g. here : [How to change status code & add message from failed AuthorizationHandler policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889688/how-to-change-status-code-add-message-from-failed-authorizationhandler-policy) )

**Problem : this doesn't seem to generate a "valid" 404 response.**
I think so for two reasons:

- When I look at Chrome's network tab, the response is NOT "404", instead it's **net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 404**
- When I look at the response data, there's only headers. **My custom error text ("Blah blah NotFound") does not appear anywhere.**

What am I doing wrong?

*Note : I've tried returning immediately after setting the 404, without doing context.Fail() but I get the same result.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The root cause:**

My Web Api had **several middlewares** working with the response value. Those middleware were **chained up** in `Startup.cs`, using the traditional `app.UseXXX()`.

Chrome *was* receiving 404 (along with my custom response body) from my Requirement middleware (hurray!), but Chrome is "smart" and by design **continues** to receive the response **even after that initial 404** -- for as long as the server continues generating some response data.

Because of that, Chrome eventually came across a **different response** added by another of the chained up middlewares. The 404 was still there, but the response body was slightly changed.

And since chrome is paranoid, it would display this `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` to indicate that **someone had messed up the consistency of the response somewhere along the chain of responders.**

==========

**The solution :**

**Finalize** your response with `Response.CompleteAsync()` to prevent any other subsequent middleware from changing it further :

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement) {

    if (context.Resource is HttpContext httpContext) {
        var endpoint = httpContext.GetEndpoint();

        if ( /* conditions for hard failure */ ) { context.Fail(); return; }
        
        if ( /* conditions for success */) {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
            return; 
        }

        // Neither a requirement success nor a requirement failure, just a different response : 

        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Blah blah NotFound");
        await httpContext.Response.CompleteAsync(); // <-- THIS!!!
        return;
    }

    context.Fail();
}
```

Please note : if **your** '`HandleRequirementAsync`' function does not have the '`async`' keyword, then do not use '`await`' inside of it, and do `return Task.CompletedTask;` instead of just `return;`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a work demo based on your code, you can refer to it.

```
public class MyAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MyRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public MyAuthorizationHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) 
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor; 
     }


    protected override  Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MyRequirement requirement) 
    {

            
            if ( /* conditions for success */) {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return; 
            }

            // If it fails at this point, I want to return 404 because of reasons.
            else
           {
            var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            httpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";            
            httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Blah blah NotFound").ConfigureAwait(false);  
           
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Did you really try that? I find it hard to believe. For a start, the C# compiler should complain that you return Task.CompletedTask from a function marked "async". I think you missed one key difference between my function and all the examples of HandleRequirementAsync in the code snippets: Mine is marked "async" because it contains a few "await"

Comment: Definitely doesn't work. If this was real code, the compiler would also complain that httpContext can be null, at : "httpContext.Response.XXX"

Comment: @jeancallisti My mistake,  I don't use "await" , so my Mine isn't marked "async".  Besides, I use "var httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;" so, I can get  httpContext .

Comment: thanks for the clarifications; all in all those were all syntactic details, the issue lied elsewhere, as pointed out in the solution I posted.