# .net core - How to return 403 on AuthorizationHandler?

Tags: api, authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

I implemented my custom AuthorizationHandler.
On that i check i the user can resolved and is active.

If the user isn't active then i would like to return an 403 status.

```
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ValidUserRequirement requirement)
{
    var userId = context.User.FindFirstValue( ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier );

    if (userId != null)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(userId);

        if (user != null)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.AddCurrentUser(user);

            if (user.Active)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                _log.LogWarning(string.Format("User ´{1}´ with id: ´{0} isn't active", userId, user.UserName), null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _log.LogWarning(string.Format("Can't find user with id: ´{0}´", userId), null);
        }
    } else
    {
        _log.LogWarning(string.Format("Can't get user id from token"), null);
    }

    context.Fail();

    var response = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response;
    response.StatusCode = 403;

}
```

But i receive a 401. Can you please help me?

Comment: Authorization != Authentication. 401 (Unauthorized) is the right status-code here, not 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: You are right! i only tryed the returning of 403, so now i can extend this methode by authentication.

Comment: HTTP 403 provides a distinct error case from HTTP 401; while HTTP 401 is returned when the client has not authenticated, and implies that a successful response may be returned following valid authentication, HTTP 403 is returned when the client is not permitted access to the resource despite providing authentication such as insufficient permissions of the authenticated account. [wikipedia].  403 should be the status code in an "authorization handler".

Comment: Based on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses) on the differences between 401 and 403, `AuthorizationHandler` should return a 403 error on a fail. 401 errors should be returned by the authentication middleware only.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68834723/6735035) answer goes into detail on how to use `IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler` to return 403 instead of 401

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could you check that on the end of your function? I'm using that in my custom middleware to rewrite status code to 401 in some cases but in your scenario should also work

```
var filterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
var response = filterContext?.HttpContext.Response;
response?.OnStarting(async () =>
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
//await response.Body.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length); only when you want to pass a message
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Single Responsibility Principle , we should not use the `HandleRequirementAsync()` method to redirect reponse , we should use middleware or  Controller to do that instead . If you put the redirect logic in `HandleRequirementAsync()` , how about if you want to use it in View page ?

You can remove the redirection-related code to somewhere else (outside) , and now you inject an `IAuthorizationService` to authorize anything as you like , even a resource-based authorization :

```
public class YourController : Controller{

    private readonly IAuthorizationService _authorizationService;
    public YourController(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        this._authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    [Authorize("YYY")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var resource  /* = ... */ ;
        var x = await this._authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(User,resource , "UserNameActiveCheck");

        if (x.Succeeded)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else {
            return new StatusCodeResult(403);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to do that for ALL my api functions. It seems to be much more work to do it for each methode than to do it once centrally.

Answer (score 1):

in .NET core 6.0 you can use the Fail method
[AuthorizationHandlerContext.Fail Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationhandlercontext.fail?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-authorization-authorizationhandlercontext-fail)

```cs
protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AppAuthorizationRequirement requirement)
{
       context.Fail(); //Use this
}
```