# AngularJS $http(...) errorHandler receives empty string for data

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple AngularJS $http block like so;

```
$http(req).then(function successCallback(response) {
    alert(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

My issue is that when my ASP.NET Controller returns a HTTP error code, the JS errorCallback receives an object like;

```
{data: "", status: 304, config: Object, statusText: "Not Modified"}
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to populate the data property in my callback.

If instead my controller returns a HTTP OK code, then the 'success' callback is invoked, and the return data is available. But not when it's an error... help!

The controller function is a WebAPI POST handler and looks like;

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Save([FromBody]object data)
{
    ...<snip>...

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified,
        Content = new JsonContent(JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            success = false,
            message = "User not authorised to perform this action."
        }))
    };
}
```

The same construct, but with;

```
StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
```

Is successfully received in the success callback in the JS.

Comment: Is that just a typo in your code? `data` vs `response`?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: yes, fixed.

Comment: What are you expecting to be in `data` when there's an error..?

Comment: @Rob; a JSON blob in the end, but I can't even get a simple string to come through. Only the HTTP status code and it's statusText

Comment: @RJLohan `304` indicates that the information will not be re-transmitted. I'm not too well versed in that - however I would bet it's because your request has been cached. See here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-4.1

Comment: Can you add a sample of the request you are sending

Comment: @Rob: wow, thanks for that. Turns out that the issue was the HTTP status code I chose. Somehow I managed to pick the only one that doesn't return data! Changing this error code produced the expected outcome, and now I better understand the situation. Just wish I'd posted this question before several days of head-on-desk action...

Comment: @RJLohan No worries - glad it led you towards getting it working properly :). Would you mind posting your solution as an answer and marking it as accepted so that it can potentially help future visitors? Thanks!

Comment: Also for future visitors: [403 (Forbidden) vs 401 (Unauthorized) status codes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after reviewing comments on my question, it turns out that the problem was caused by my selection of Http status codes. I was returning

```
StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotModified,
```

This code has a special meaning, and it seems the 'data' blob is intentionally stripped.

Instead, if I use a code like

```
StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
```

The 'data' blob is populated as expected in the Angular callback.

This sample returns the expected error data;

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Save([FromBody]object data)
{
    ...<snip>...

    return new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
        Content = new JsonContent(JObject.FromObject(new
        {
            success = false,
            message = "User not authorised to perform this action."
        }))
    };
}
```