# Error message “Forbidden You don't have permission to access on one page

Tags: http-status-code-403

On http://www.raogk.org/alabama-genealogy/ I get a

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /alabama-genealogy/ on this server.
```

It one occurs for a single page. Why do I get this?

Comment: check this answer to find the reason behind status code 403. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/1898397

Comment: I understand what the 403 means but dont understand why it is giving me this error on just one page. No other pages are are giving me this. I am the owner / admin

Comment: Only problem with that picture is that it doesn't have error code 418. That's a critical one