# TFS 2010 to 2015 upgrade "HTTP code 403: Forbidden"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We have migrated from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 recently(we are using VS 2015). We have followed the instructions specified in Microsoft Website for TFS 2015 and SQL 2012 installation. We have successfully restored all the databases from 2010 server to 2015 server and attached all the project collections in TFS 2015.

Now when we connect to TFS 2015(we don't have any connectivity Issues to TFS) from VS 2015 and then try to "get latest version" for any of the available projects, we are getting

> "HTTP code 403: Forbidden" error message.

Pls help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoT3P.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "we don't have any connectivity Issues to TFS"? Is web access (http://myserver:8080/tfs or https://myserver/tfs) available and can you view and download your sources from there? It might help to run the Best Practices Analyzer from the TFS power tools (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) against your installation to see if there is anything out of order with your configuration.

Comment: We are able to connect to TFS 2015 from VS 2015 with out any issues, but when i try to "Get Latest Version" i see "403 error" message while downloading the code.Also am part of admin group (so i dont think it could be a permission issue).

Comment: Is your user able to view/download sources from web access? Permission are very specific on some points in TFS so you might be able to view sources, work items and everything but not "get latest" because you do not have that permission or have a deny for that permission. Check the source control permission for your specific user that might give you some clues. Since you went from TFS 2010 to TFS 2015 check your default access level/license as well as Patrick suggested, that whole part was introduced in TFS2012, so it might be the culprit here.

Comment: Users are able to view the code for the projects they have been granted access, but when users\admin try to get "latest version", we see "403 error" .Cross checked the permissions and license everything looks good

Comment: Have you been able to run the best practice analyzer against your installation? (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) Did that give you any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Receiving a **403 response** is the server telling you, “I’m sorry. I know
>   who you are–I believe who you say you are–but you just don’t have
>   permission to access this resource. Maybe if you ask the system
>   administrator nicely, you’ll get permission. But please don’t bother
>   me again until your predicament changes.”
>
> More details please see
>   ：[403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)

So this error seems to be a permission issue. First please double check if you have assigned sufficient permissions such as add in  the group **contributors** . Besides check if you have got any deny permission for getting files. In TFS, deny trumps allow.

If all of you including administrator still can't do this, please pay attention to your [license](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/buy-access-tfs-test-hub).

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with "dynamicIpSecurity" setting in configuration file which has a limitation of maxRequests="40" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="5000" which is the reason for failure when request limit reaches 40

Comment: Dynamic IP Restriction Settings was my issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, I went to Manage Connections within Visual Studio and then I had to use the switch user link to force a reconnect. Once I did this the team projects I had access to showed up.