# cannot integrate Jenkins with TFS

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to integrate Jenkins (2.32.2) with TFS 2013. I have installed the necessary Tfs plugin (5.3.1). However, when I try to configure the TFS plugin in Jenkins to contact the TFS Team Project Collections by mentioning THE URL of the default collection of TFS (http://10.100.2.69:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/) and the correct credentials, 
I get an error "javax.ServletException: com.microsoft.tfs.core.exceptions.TECoreExceptions: the soap endpoint http://10.100.2.69:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Services/v1.0/Regitration.asmx could not be contacted"[image: image showing error]

**Note**: I have managed to configure this successfully on my local environment at work, but cannot configure in the clients environment. The credentials are correct. Can it be something with the proxy settings at the clients end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Receiving a **403 response** is the server telling you, “I’m sorry. I know
>   who you are–I believe who you say you are–but you just don’t have
>   permission to access this resource. Maybe if you ask the system
>   administrator nicely, you’ll get permission. But please don’t bother
>   me again until your predicament changes.”
>
> More details please see
>   ：[403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)

So this error seems not related to your credentials. You need to make sure the **system proxy settings were correct** - sometimes after upgrading to the latest version of the plugin it may be using the default Java system proxy.

You could check the info here: **Jenkins > Plugin Manager > Advanced** to match the wildcard domain that your TFS server resided on.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Patrick-MSFT
The problem was with the sytem proxy settings. I ran the config without any proxy settings and it worked.