# Is admin vs access level HTTP responses?

Tags: http, response

I have Laravel CMS and I am confusing with HTTP responses.

If the logged user is not admin (should I use 401).
If the logged user not have privilege  to open specific page (should I use 403).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)

Comment: If you're not logged in, 401. If you're logged in as the wrong account, 403.

Answer (score 1):

You got it correct. Those are the appropriate status codes for each of those situations.