# What is the most appropriate HTTP Status Code for Invalid Host/Referer request header?

Tags: http, security, web, server, http-status-codes

I'm writing an Node.js/NPM module for protecting express servers against [DNS Rebind attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) through server-side Host and Referer [sic] header validation. The server admin specifies whitelisted Hosts and/or Referers, and any requests that don't include those whitelisted values will receive error status codes and no results.

**What would be the most appropriate [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) to return to the client when they provide an invalid Host or Referer header in their request, or when they fail to provide one at all when one is required?** I'm thinking 401 Unauthorized, but I wanted to get a second opinion. An argument could also be made for 400 Bad Request, or I suppose, 412 Precondition Failed.

Does the server have an obligation to notify the client why their request is being rejected via response headers or body (e.g. A whitelisted Host is required) or is it ok to respond with an error code and leave the client wondering for security/obfuscation purposes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be correct, best match seems to be **Unauthorized**. But the best matching HTTP status code is not 401, it is actually **403**.

403 status code says `The request was valid, but the server is refusing action. The user might not have the necessary permissions for a resource, or may need an account of some sort.` and the latter part of this sentence fits your use case perfectly.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/945214

To all unauthorized/unauthenticated requests, it is not advisable to respond back with any explaination as it would be an information leakage from your server: http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246936/Information%20Leakage.

Comment: Right you are! These links and quotes are helpful. Turns out I was sending a 401 without the required WWW-Authentication header, which violates the spec. 403 Forbidden does seem to be more appropriate. After reading some of those ^ links, it does seem that "Unauthenticated" would be a more appropriate name for the 401 "Unauthorized" status code...