# Why is the `Content-Encoding` header named that way?

Tags: http, encoding, http-headers, compression

**Background**

A server can send a `Content-Encoding` header to indicate if, and how, the content of the response body has been *compressed*. E.g.

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

A server can also send a `Content-Type` header to indicate the media type, and optionally provide the standard used to *encode* the content. E.g.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Therefore, it seems that the *encoding* of the content is specified in the `Content-Type` header, and not the `Content-Encoding` header.

---

**Question**

During the design of the HTTP standard, what's the rationale behind the naming of the `Content-Encoding` header? (Over, say `Content-Compression`) Is this a similar case of bad naming like the [`401 Unauthorized` response code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses#comment62077971_3297048)?