# 401 Unauthorized vs 403 Forbidden: Which is the right status code for when the user has not logged in?

Tags: http-status-code-403, http-status-codes, http-status-code-401

After lots of Googling and Stackoverflowing, it still isn't clear to me because many articles and questions/answers were too general (including [403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses) which was not specifically for my use-case).

Question: What's the proper HTTP Status Code when the user has not logged in and requests to see some pages that should be shown only to logged-in users?

Comment: Related post - [403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3297048/465053)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The exact satisfying one-time-for-all answer I found is:

Short answer:

#### 401 Unauthorized

---

Description:

While we know first is **authentication** (has the user ***logged-in*** or not?) and then we will go into **authorization** (does he have the needed ***privilege*** or not?), but here's the key that makes us mistake:

> **But isn’t “401 Unauthorized” about authorization, not authentication?**
>
> Back when the HTTP spec (RFC 2616) was written, the two words may not
> have been as widely understood to be distinct. It’s clear from the
> description and other supporting texts that 401 is about
> authentication.

From [HTTP Status Codes 401 Unauthorized and 403 Forbidden for Authentication and Authorization (and OAuth)](https://robertlathanh.com/2012/06/http-status-codes-401-unauthorized-and-403-forbidden-for-authentication-and-authorization-and-oauth/).

So maybe, if we want to rewrite the standards! focusing enough on each words, we may refer to the following table:

```
Status Code | Old foggy naming | New clear naming | Use case
+++++++++++ | ++++++++++++++++ | ++++++++++++++++ | ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
401         | Unauthorized     | Unauthenticated  | User has not logged-in
403         | Forbidden        | Unauthorized     | User doesn't have enough privilege
```

Comment: This is only true if you are using HTTP authentication (and not, for instance, something based on cookies … like OAuth) since you must send a WWW-Authenticate header when you make a 401 response.

Comment: In my case, I am using it on API. If the user does not supply an API Key I will return 401, and if he supplied an API key but does not have enough privilege I will return 403? Am I correct?

Comment: I do not think this is correct. Check out the RFC quotes in @Quentin 's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50143750/333331

Comment: I don't want to play on words, but maybe 401 should have been tagged "Unauthenticated"? To me, Forbidden and Unauthorised are synonym, IRL. Authenticated means: "we know you are who you say you are".

Answer (score 31):

It depends on the mechanism you use to perform the login.

The spec for [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) says:

> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server
> understood    the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that
> wishes to    make public why the request has been forbidden can
> describe that    reason in the response payload (if any).
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access.  The client
> SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same
> credentials.  **The client MAY repeat the request with new or different
> credentials.**  However, a request might be forbidden for reasons
> unrelated to the credentials.

While [401 Unauthorized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) is not defined in the main HTTP status codes spec but is in [the HTTP Authentication spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) and says:

> The 401 (Unauthorized) status code indicates that the request has not
> been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for
> the target resource.  **The server generating a 401 response MUST send
> a WWW-Authenticate header field** (Section 4.1) containing at least one
> challenge applicable to the target resource.

---

So if you are using `WWW-Authenticate` and `Authorization` headers as your authentication mechanism, use 401. If you are using any other method, then use 403.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. Those RFC quotes are key.

Answer (score -3):

IMO It would depend the type of resource you are trying to query. Sounds more logical that way. Forbidden refers more to files or folders of a website, or resources in general, while Unauthorized is more logical to use if some sort of type of execution is required, page scripts etc.

Comment: Funny, the user who downvoted my answer was removed...;)