# "500 Error: Cannot exchange code for grant in bearer-only mode" after successful browser login in Keycloak

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect, keycloak

User trying to access */hello* url in the browser via a reverse-proxy.

> "500 Error: Cannot exchange code for grant in bearer-only mode"

error is popped after successful login by the user on Keycloak login page on access to protected url.

The following code is used in the reverse proxy:

```
var Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');
var session = require('express-session');
var memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

let keycloak = new Keycloak(memoryStore);
app = express();
app.use( keycloak.middleware() );
app.get( '/hello', keycloak.protect( 'realm:admin' ));
```

keycloak.json is:

```
{
  "realm": "master",
  "auth-server-url": "https://127.0.0.1/auth",  
  "resource": "test_ui",
  "confidential-port": 0,  
  "credentials" : {
    "password" : "d31c4718-12e9-407b-9bf2-cb72734a23f0"
  }
}
```

client *test_ui* is confidential.
Adding `bearer-only : true` to *keycloak.json* results in access denied error instead of the above error.

What's wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Hello! Practical solution example: change the realm, app code and cURL example. Credible sources: Official keycloak documentation, oAuth RFC. I have also edited my answer to make the required steps to fix your issue simpler to understand. Take another look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: your `keycloak.json` config and node.js `keycloak.protect` app code are unaligned:

- `keycloak.json` describes `"realm":"master"`
- But you are invoking `keycloak.protection` on your app's `GET /hello` resource for `admin` realm only: `app.get( '/hello', keycloak.protect( 'realm:admin' ));`

### TRY CHANGING THE REALM TO MASTER

`app.get( '/hello', keycloak.protect( 'realm:master' ));`

### YOU CAN TEST IF IT WORKS USING cURL

```
curl -i http://YOUR_APP_SERVER_HOST/hello -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN"
```

### DON'T FORGET TO SET UP BEARER AUTHENTICATION ON KEYCLOAK

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/authorization_services/topics/enforcer/keycloak-enforcement-bearer.html

### AND GET YOUR BEARER TOKEN FIRST

```
curl \
  -d 'client_id=YOUR_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT' \
  -d 'username=YOUR_USERNAME' \
  -d 'password=YOUR_PASSWORD' \
  -d 'grant_type=password' \
  'https://YOUR_KEYCLOAK_SERVER_HOST/auth/realms/YOUR_REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token'
```

### NOW, THE LITERATURE

What happens here is essentially:

- On your first request: you are trying to access functionality that requires Bearer token authentication, but you are using grant exchange code instead. Hence the error 500 response. Are you authenticating first against your keycloak `/auth` authentication service endpoint using your user credentials in order to obtain a valid Bearer token for that realm? Or are you, on the contrary, mistakenly trying to use your user credentials to authenticate directly against your app's service `GET /hello` API resource endpoint instead?
- Then, on your second request you try enabling Bearer only authentication, but:

  1. Your client is not examining the provided response WWW-Authenticate header for determining the required authentication method and, most importantly:
  2. **Your client is not issuing a new `GET /hello` request providing a valid HTTP** `Authorization` **header with your obtained Bearer token valid for `GET /hello`'s assigned realm**. Therefore you simply get an HTTP authentication error response (Typically `401 Unauthorized` HTTP response, although `403 Forbidden` [is sometimes used instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)).

In short, you need to align the realm and auth scheme on client and app server and auth server config, so:

- Your app server endpoint `GET /hello` will send a `WWW-Authenticate` HTTP header specifying the required user realm and authentication scheme.
- Your client will then use the provided user credentials to authenticate on your keycloak authentication server and receive a Bearer token.

> *You must have configured the keycloak authentication server to support the required authentication scheme for that realm and the user must have permissions to operate on that realm. Check out the keycloak server administrative console for that purpose.*

- Finally, once this is done for that realm and authentication scheme, your client will be able to issue a `GET /hello` request to your app server containing the acquired HTTP Bearer token on the HTTP `Authorization` header. cURL example:

  curl -i http://example.com/api/hello -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken123"

For more info:

- Bearer authentication flow is described on [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-6.1.1) *OAuth 2.0 Bearer Token Usage* as part of the OAuth 2.0 standard.
- [Keycloack documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/authorization_services/topics/enforcer/keycloak-enforcement-bearer.html) describes how to set up bearer token authentication on `keycloak.json`.
- [The described steps to protect your node.js application](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/securing_apps/topics/oidc/nodejs-adapter.html) `GET /hello` resource (You might want to use a custom handler).
- The docs on the predefined keycloak [master realm](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/server_admin/topics/realms/master.html) (sort of an admin scope) and how to [create a new realm](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.1/server_admin/topics/realms/create.html), user scoped, for your app's users.