# Java SAX parser throwing 403 exception for valid URL

Tags: java, saxparser

The SAX parser is throwing 403 exception for a valid URL, which loads without any issues in a browser. We are able to reproduce the problem with the sample code that follows. Pointers appreciated.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;    
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SAXParserFactory factory2 = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            String uri;
            uri = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326801/000132680119000009/FilingSummary.xml"; // Does not work
            // uri = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"; // ** Works if this line is uncommented **
            SAXParser saxParser = factory2.newSAXParser();
            DefaultHandler eventHandler = new DefaultHandler();
            saxParser.parse(uri, eventHandler);
            // ...
            // Business Logic
            // ...
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }
        catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The stacktrace is as follows:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1326801/000132680119000009/FilingSummary.xml
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at StackOverflow.main(StackOverflow.java:15)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/2970947

Comment: I would start by using that URI with ordinary java code to download it. You are correct, the URL works in a browser. Beyond that, add your stacktrace to the question!

Comment: Stacktrace has been added now.

Comment: Some servers may decide to send you an HTTP 403 in case your user agent is not what they expect (e.g. only web browsers allowed).