# download files by bypassing Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js

all my request return state code 403 yet through the the mother-website it doesn't.

this is for a node.js based code piece.

modules i used:
fs, request

```js
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')

let file = fs.createWriteStream('./try.jpg')

request('https://ba.hitomi.la/galleries/1402385/33_31.jpg', { encoding: null, headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, x-requested-with, content-type, accept' } }, (error, response, body) => {
}).pipe(file)
```

i need an full code that can download / fetching data through the website.

Comment: 401 means there is no authentication, so, you need to pass some auth data in your headers https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/6066986

Comment: @Grynets sorry, just edited. it was 403.

Comment: CORS is managed on the server, setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the client request has no effect and is likely ignored by the server. CORS isn't even relevant outside of a web browser.