# serviceAccount Token Volume Projection - Projected Token in "path" in manifest file is incorrect

Tags: kubernetes

I am using serviceAccount Token Volume projection as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection). This is the manifest file I'm using:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pod-acr
spec:
  containers:
  - image: yorchaksacr.azurecr.io/busybox:1.0
    name: busybox
    command: ["/bin/sh","-c","sleep 36000"]
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/tokens
      name: vault-token
  serviceAccountName: pull-acr-images
  volumes:
  - name: vault-token
    projected:
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          path: vault-token
          expirationSeconds: 7200
          audience: vault
```

As expected, the token is mounted to the container under `/var/run/secrets/tokens/vault-token`:

```
/ # ls -la /var/run/secrets/tokens
total 4
drwxrwxrwt    3 root     root           100 Jul 24 21:35 .
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root          4096 Jul 24 21:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            60 Jul 24 21:35 ..2019_07_24_21_35_15.018111081
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            31 Jul 24 21:35 ..data -> ..2019_07_24_21_35_15.018111081
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            18 Jul 24 21:35 vault-token -> ..data/vault-token
```

Problem is if I try to authenticate to the API server using this token the API rejects the call with `401 Unauthorized`:

```
/ # wget --header="Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/tokens/vault-token)" --no-check-certificate https://10.2.1.19:6443
Connecting to 10.2.1.19:6443 (10.2.1.19:6443)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
```

However if I use the default path and token where service account tokens are projected for all pods `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceacconts/token` that works:

```
/ # wget --header="Authorization: Bearer $(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" --no-check-certificate https://10.2.1.19:6443
Connecting to 10.2.1.19:6443 (10.2.1.19:6443)
saving to 'index.html'
index.html           100% |************************************************************************************************************************************************************|  2738  0:00:00 ETA
'index.html' saved
```

If I `cat` both tokens I can see they are actually different:

```
# cat /var/run/secrets/tokens/vault-token
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IiJ9.eyJhdWQiOlsidmF1bHQiXSwiZXhwIjoxNTY0MDEzMjcwLCJpYXQiOjE1NjQwMDYwNzAsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vMTAuMi4xLjE5Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pbyI6eyJuYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZWZhdWx0IiwicG9kIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJwb2QtYWNyIiwidWlkIjoiNThiNjI5YWEtZGU4Ni00YTAzLWI3YmQtMTI4ZGFiZWVkYmQ5In0sInNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Ijp7Im5hbWUiOiJwdWxsLWFjci1pbWFnZXMiLCJ1aWQiOiJlZGE0NDlmYS1iODE2LTQ0ZGMtYTFjNi0yMWJhZWUwZmVkN2YifX0sIm5iZiI6MTU2NDAwNjA3MCwic3ViIjoic3lzdGVtOnNlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50OmRlZmF1bHQ6cHVsbC1hY3ItaW1hZ2VzIn0.UjPaTgWHPwCeeh1ltBb64hv0yEjKkRxKw_BZ3PLDA3HsJK-keXN40Khp-8mNnLQ-uYIfMgW4FXwYIm0SVeQUhM4sh4rwjAYDEfEHDah9AvhEL8I65T_jhnhT10E1M7mzk1x0RFGvjZAECd1RlYM7IuXIkEfZCI_6GRVAbX3Vmk6XF0sRh2T8DZzw8kj_Z54J2gYCt2beBnn7hC9rOC9LW9J0AFEAAQQE_UJME5y4jZD6hfJMSGOouyQm70nVGytqKVsLbzyorH5pugEqrs1Z_dLx6E3Ta9kELRPvyDZgeNiS44fEYlRApn6fZawsppc1oRNoeyMqiIPRdgQekBVfTA/ #


# cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJkZWZhdWx0Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9zZWNyZXQubmFtZSI6InB1bGwtYWNyLWltYWdlcy10b2tlbi1oYjU0NyIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VydmljZS1hY2NvdW50Lm5hbWUiOiJwdWxsLWFjci1pbWFnZXMiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50L3NlcnZpY2UtYWNjb3VudC51aWQiOiJlZGE0NDlmYS1iODE2LTQ0ZGMtYTFjNi0yMWJhZWUwZmVkN2YiLCJzdWIiOiJzeXN0ZW06c2VydmljZWFjY291bnQ6ZGVmYXVsdDpwdWxsLWFjci1pbWFnZXMifQ.nqqhZVmBUuKVi6E3L9MEn8oW1dKd-DV4c9jcVy5mXAuEMZ1WgLlaaHFF1ibnVMjEK6VUJyJhp7w08hgSmyyh-KY4BQ5oJf1jmSySvmttJxjXW-KsMpf5rHF0ZDmgaqZwbi7FvowtoTECstFBVNoszKJUn1iV5mU_6MQkEtGTNyE4KuZ9LEvPuZxiNZ5UyW3UaHXLqF63-w_xlkfa_75E-cgXqvSSGTCb6RsTuOmVyCqganx5SpIb5EU-3Mu7hUWEhSRAh3tpcPIwjS7-NkuO0ReH7Z40rPHqkIokshUUO75WM_oPq7tlu6PSCTwOK-Jw66kzi-jqKNyKvMeWJUq4WQ/ #
```

Does anybody have an idea why am I seeing this behavior? I would expect both tokens to work, but apparently looks like it is not the case.

Configuration of the API Server:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=10.2.1.19
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --insecure-port=0
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.96.0.0/12
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key
    - --basic-auth-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/passwordfile
    - --service-account-issuer=https://10.2.1.19
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    image: k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver:v1.15.1
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Comment: Decoding those tokens with https://jwt.io/, both tokens appear to have the same subject, so I suspect it's not an authorization problem.  Perhaps it's an authentication problem then?  I notice that the issuer (`"iss"` key in the JWT) is different for the two tokens...

Comment: ... The docs section on "Service Account Token Volume Projection" that you linked mentions certain flags that need to be passed when running the API server. Looks slightly out of date, the flag names have changed slightly, probably depends on what version of K8s you're running. See flags [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/). Can you check the values of the appropriate flags and update your question with that info?

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Thanks for looking into this. These are the flags I am using. I agree with you this is an authorization problem since I am getting 401 - Unauthorized as a response. I am running v1.15.1, but I was experiencing the same issue with v1.13.8. The question is why is the issuer different for both tokens since they are both related to the same service account. I have edited my question with the flags enabled for the API server.

Comment: Confusingly, a 401 Unauthorized means an authentication error (meaning that it couldn't authenticate that the subject making the request really is the subject it claims to be, in this case, via its bearer token).  An authorization error would instead return a 403 Forbidden typically. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses). So it is indeed an authentication error...

Comment: ... I think the logic for authenticating tokens is more complex than the flag descriptions make it sound. I can't fully grok: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/8993fbc543c18e73668793b5d5e234c0a136735c/pkg/kubeapiserver/authenticator/config.go, in particular, I can't understand why `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token` works. However, I have a hunch as to why `/var/run/secrets/tokens/vault-token` doesn't work. As the flag descriptions say, the token authenticator will try to validate that the bound audiences match the value of `--api-audiences` flag...

Comment: ... and if that flag isn't set, then it defaults to matching against the `--service-account-issuer`. Well the problem is your token is bound to audiences `["vault"]` but the issuer is `https://10.2.1.19`. What happens if you leave out `audience: vault` from your pod spec, or, alternatively, replace it with `audience: https://10.2.1.19`?  I'm assuming here that it's easier for you to change your pod spec and retry than it is to restart the kube-apiserver with different flags.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help here @AmitKumarGupta. As you mentioned, replacing audience in my pod spec to match ``--service-account-issuer`` solved the problem

Comment: Cool, I'll summarize in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Confusingly, 401 Unauthorized indicates an authentication problem rather than an authorization problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses)). This means the Kubernetes service account token authenticator doesn't like the token at `/var/run/secrets/tokens/vault-token` (let's call it the `vault-token`).  The two tokens differ in a couple ways. Here's the decoded `vault-token`:

```
{
  "aud": [
    "vault"
  ],
  "exp": 1564013270,
  "iat": 1564006070,
  "iss": "https://10.2.1.19",
  "kubernetes.io": {
    "namespace": "default",
    "pod": {
      "name": "pod-acr",
      "uid": "58b629aa-de86-4a03-b7bd-128dabeedbd9"
    },
    "serviceaccount": {
      "name": "pull-acr-images",
      "uid": "eda449fa-b816-44dc-a1c6-21baee0fed7f"
    }
  },
  "nbf": 1564006070,
  "sub": "system:serviceaccount:default:pull-acr-images"
}
```

Notice the audiences (`["vault"]`), issuer (`"https://10.2.1.19"`), and subject (`"system:serviceaccount:default:pull-acr-images"`).

Here's the `default-path-token`:

```
{
  "iss": "kubernetes/serviceaccount",
  "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/namespace": "default",
  "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/secret.name": "pull-acr-images-token-hb547",
  "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-account.name": "pull-acr-images",
  "kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/service-account.uid": "eda449fa-b816-44dc-a1c6-21baee0fed7f",
  "sub": "system:serviceaccount:default:pull-acr-images"
}
```

Same subject, but different issuer (`"kubernetes/serviceaccount"`) and no audiences.

I'm not sure why the `default-path-token` has a different issuer, or why it's authenticating correctly, but your `vault-token` is not authenticating correctly because the audiences don't match the issuer.

More specifically, the clue is in the doc you linked [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#service-account-token-volume-projection). It says that this feature working correctly depends on how you set the following flags for the `kube-apiserver`:

- `--service-account-issuer`
- `--service-account-signing-key-file`
- `--service-account-api-audiences`

Not sure if those docs are wrong or just out of date, but since you're using `v1.15.1` the flags are now called:

- `--service-account-issuer`
- `--service-account-signing-key-file string`
- `--api-audiences`

The [flag documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) says of the `--api-audiences` flag:

> Identifiers of the API. The service account token authenticator will validate that tokens used against the API are bound to at least one of these audiences. If the --service-account-issuer flag is configured and this flag is not, this field defaults to a single element list containing the issuer URL.

Since you *don't* have this flag set and you have `--service-account-issuer=https://10.2.1.19`, and you have `audience: vault` in your pod spec, your token is going to claim its bound to the `vault` audience, and the token authenticator is going to try to match this against the value of the `--service-account-issuer` flag, and clearly those don't match.

You can make these match by specifying `audience: https://10.2.1.19` in your pod spec instead of `audience: vault`. One caveat: this solution may technically work to ensure the token authenticates, but I'm not sure what the truly *right* answer is insofar as using this flags and fields in the pod spec as they're truly intended, and just making these strings match could be a bit hacky.