# .Net Core API UnauthorizedResult 401 status?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

**Understanding**

Today I was reading about `401` vs `403` Status Codes. I came across an interesting post on SO which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses).

As per post, my understanding is

1. `401` - Authentication failed.
2. `403` - Authorization failed.

**Use Case**

In `.Net Core Web API`, I used `UnauthorizedResult` in one of the custom filter (I know filters are not preferred way to go for authorization checks but that is a separate discussion altogether). This `ActionResult` do return `401` Status Code however I expected it to return 403 as per above mentioned post as it is Authorization failure and not Authentication. Interface used is also `IAuthorizationFilter`.

**Question**

Should not `UnauthorizedResult` return `403` instead of `401`? Am I missing something on above understanding?

**Side Note**

To solve the problem, I used `StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden` to return `403`.

Comment: It's a little confusing, but you can use [`ForbidResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.forbidresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for the `403`.

Comment: I understand...the question is actually not about solving the problem...I already solved it. But about the expected behavior? BTW, did you meant my question is confusing?

Comment: No, I meant Unauthorized vs Forbid etc can be a bit confusing.

Comment: .NET got these backwards. UnauthorizedResult should be returning a 403, not a 401 - this is a logged in user that does not have rights to a resource. ForbidResult should be returning a 401, not a 403 - this is a not logged in user status code.