# How to transfer data to a host with a username and password

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a problem. Current problem is that I want to transfer some data to a host with an username and password, but I keep getting the same error message. I would be very happy if you help.

My conf file:

```
input { 
   file { 
      path => "........../*.txt"
      start_position => "beginning"
      sincedb_path => "NUL" 
   }
}
filter {
............. 
}
output {
    elasticsearch { 
      hosts => "xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx" 
      manage_template => false 
      index => "my_index_name"
      document_type => "my_index_name" 
      user => "my_user_name"
      password => "my_password" 
    }
```

Error message:

> [WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect
> connection to dead ES instance, but got an error
> {:url=>"http://elastic_user_name:xxxxxx@xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/",
> :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError,
> :message=>"Got response code '403' contacting Elasticsearch at URL
> 'http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/'"}

I also made changes to logstash.yml and elasticsearch.yml files as follows, but I got the same error.

> elasticsearch.yml: xpack.management.elasticsearch.username:
> my_elastic_user_name xpack.management.elasticsearch.password:
> my_password

> logstash.yml: xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.username:
> my_elastic_user_name xpack.monitoring.elasticsearch.password:
> my_password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiving a HTTP 403 response code ("Forbidden") indicates that your user does not have permissions to index data to Elasticsearch (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/11486670) for the difference between Unauthorized (401) and Forbidden (403)).

Your user should have the following permissions

[image]

Setting up such a role is described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.x/ls-security.html).

Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-privileges.html) about security privileges in order to adapt it to your use case.

For xpack monitoring you should create a user with the logstash_system [built-in role](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/built-in-roles.html).

I hope I could help you.