# Do not redirect if guest?

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to use `guest` middleware yet, if the `request->expectsJson()` it does not redirect, just errors? (Like the auth middleware).

Or would I need to write custom middleware?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Redirect a user when they're not logged in?

Comment: I do not want to redirect a user if logged in, if they are logged in I want to return an unauthorised error.

Comment: I assume you mean that you want to return an unauthorised error when the user **is not** logged in right? If not, please try to elaborate because it's a little confusing.

Comment: User in unauthroised if they are logged in e.g. allow guests but not authed users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own middleware inspired by `RedirectIfAuthenticated`:

**app/Http/Middleware/AbortIfAuthenticated.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AbortIfAuthenticated
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;

        foreach ($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                abort(403, "Not allowed");
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then replace the middleware by your own in **app/Http/Kernel.php**
(Or add a new one)

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\AbortIfAuthenticated::class,
    ...
];
```

Comment: Thanks, why a 403 and not a 401?

Comment: Because he is logged-in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297048/403-forbidden-vs-401-unauthorized-http-responses