# Power BI: 401 error when trying to acquire an access token (ConfidentialClientApplication.acquireTokenByClientCredential())

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-ad-msal

Code (basically the same as the sample application in the Azure tutorial for Power BI embedded):

```
    private async getAccessToken() {
        const clientApplication = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication({
            auth: {
                clientId: config.authClientID,
                authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${config.authTenantID}`,
                clientSecret: config.authClientSecret,
            }
        });

        return await clientApplication.acquireTokenByClientCredential({
            scopes: ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default'],
        });
    }
```

I have verified that the following parameters are correct:

- `config.authClientID`
- `config.authTenantID`
- `config.authClientSecret`

I also have:

- Granted all possible Power BI Service permissions to my Service Principal (in the Azure App Registration).
- Granted access for my Service Principal in the Power BI admin portal (through a security group).

Here's the error I get when running this function:

```
network_error: Network request failed. Please check network trace to determine root cause. | Fetch client threw: Error: HTTP status code 401 | Attempted to reach: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{my tenant id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error says that you can't reach that url. Do you have any firewall rules that prevents you from reaching https://login.microsoftonline.com ?

Comment: @abaci The error says that I am not authorized. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937030/7162167): "Receiving a 401 response is the server telling you, “you aren’t authenticated–either not authenticated at all or authenticated incorrectly–but please reauthenticate and try again.”". I do not have any firewall rules preventing me from reaching login.microsoftonline.com.

Comment: Try to generate token with **same parameters** via **[Postman](https://i.imgur.com/FZ8O0vR.png)** and check whether you are getting token or not.